# D3js: force directed, collapsing internal nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In that example of d3js http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288, which part of code handle the collapsing internal nodes where they are clicked. The event handler `click` sets the data for the colour but I don't see which part is handling the collapsing effect. Of course `link.exit().remove()` and `node.exit().remove()` remove the points and links. But how the "exit" section is created?

Answer (score 0):

This part does the job added comments to the scriplet:

```
function click(d) {
  if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
    if (d.children) { 
      //if the node is expanded the d.children will have nodes in it.
      //we are moving the nodes into another variable d._children
      d._children = d.children;
      //making d.children as null so that the exit function will remove the nodes in update.
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      //the node is collapsed state so moving the d._children back into variable d.children
      d.children = d._children;
      //making the d._children null
      d._children = null;
    }
    //after resetting/setting the d.children call update for appending nodes in case of expand(d.children have values) or remove nodes and links when (d.children have no values) 
    update();
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What this will change `var nodes = flatten(root), links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);`. I guess that these values have to change no?

Comment: no flatten is meant to get all the nodes from the nested structure of teh root. and `links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes)` generates the links.

Comment: In your comment you say `making d.children as null so that the exit function will remove the nodes in update.` So that means that `link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });` will change the selection. I don't understand why if `d.children` is null, the selection will be impacted.

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand but if the links are removed (the same for the nodes), that means that `link.exit().remove();` is updated no? Otherwise how d3js can know which links has to been removed?

Comment: yes if you remove the node the link will also vanish the reason is this line `link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });` will create selections for all links which have traget.id so all those links for which the target.id or node is removed via `link.exit().remove()`. I think you need to read this tutorial  https://medium.com/@c_behrens/enter-update-exit-6cafc6014c36#.e77lbxc9d...